# AJAX request to FOSUser to create a user

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

To test FOSUser, I'm simulating an AJAX request that send a JSON data containing the username, his email and password.

JavaScript side (far-from-perfect ajax request, but I'll use Angular in real development):

```
function ajaxPost(url, data, callback, isJson) {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", url);
    req.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {               
            callback(req.responseText);
        } else {
            console.error(req.status + " " + req.statusText + " " + url);
        }
    });
    req.addEventListener("error", function () {
        console.error("Network error at " + url);
    });
    if (isJson) {
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    req.send(data);
}

// Simulates an AJAX request to create a user from a form:
user = prompt("Username:");
email = prompt("Email:");
password = prompt("Password:");
data = { user, email, password };
ajaxPost("http://domain.tld/app_dev.php/createuser", data, console.log, true);
```

Symfony side:

```
/**
* @Route("/createuser", name="createUser")
*/
public function createUserAction($data, UserManager $userManager)
{
    $data = json_decode($data);
    if (!$userManager->findUserByUsername($data->username) && !$userManager->findUserByEmail($data->email)) {
        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setUsername($data->username);
        $user->setEmail($data->email);
        $password = password_hash($data->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $user->setPassword($password);
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        return new Response("<html><body>New user created!</body></html>");
    } else {
        return new Response("<html><body>This user or email already exists.</body></html>");
    }
}
```

When I directly go to /createuser and pass a mock-up data, it works; but when I send my ajax request, it always returns a 500 internal server error:

> [2017-06-17 08:31:49] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object" at
>   C:\wamp64\www\MyWebsite\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultCont‌​roller.php
>   line 50 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException‌​(code:
>   0): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object at
>   C:\wamp64\www\MyWebsite\src\AppBundle\Controller\Defa‌​ultController.php:50‌​)"}
>   []" That's: if (!$userManager->findUserByUsername($data->userna

Any idea? :)

Comment: Can you provide some information about the error? Extract it from the log

Comment: I forgot to look at them... Not used to Symfony yet: "[2017-06-17 08:31:49] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" at C:\wamp64\www\MyWebsite\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 50 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object at C:\\wamp64\\www\\MyWebsite\\src\\AppBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController.php:50)"} []"

That's: if (!$userManager->findUserByUsername($data->userna...

Comment: could you do `dump($data)` after `$data = json_decode($data);`?

Comment: If I var_dump the $data, I must access the page directly, because it won't do anything from an asynchronous request. So it works when I do that. I just don't understand why there's a problem with $data when the AJAX request is sent. (Symfony cache has been deleted)

Comment: simply json_decode produces an array but you are trying to access it like an object ($data->username)  try this ($data['username'])

Comment: It does not, $assoc option is false by default:http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: To be a little bit clearer; when I pass a mock-up data, I receive `object(stdClass)[617]
  public 'username' => string 'Jean' (length=4)
  public 'email' => string 'jean@email.com' (length=14)
  public 'password' => string 'jeanpass' (length=8)` with the following data: `$defaultData = '{ "username": "Jean", "email": "jean@email.com", "password": "jeanpass" }';` The exact same format as JSON.stringify() does.

Comment: When I put $assoc to true, $data is still empty. I got this error `[2017-06-17 09:16:24] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException: "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO `user` (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, 0, null, "$2y$10$k79QjAyN7cOHFhg5Z7oiSu64IfNGV7cPr08ZX5G.qcLYCsm4Vt\/82", null, null, null, "a:0:{}"]:`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm stupid. $data is nothing; I must use $request->getContent()...

```
public function createUserAction(Request $request, UserManager $userManager)
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent());
```

Thanks all for your comments :)